# Detect id of div with hammer.js / by touch

Tags: jquery, touch, hammer.js

I've got a grid of images with ID's. When a user pinches on a mobile touch device I want to detect over which one of those instances the user pinches. So instead of creating 30 hammer instances for every ID that try and detect the pinch I want to detect it the other way around. I hope my question is clear.

Cheers!

Comment: Do you use jQuery too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `event`-object to determine the current `target`:

```
$(document).on('touchstart', function(e){
    $(e.target) // this is your element
});
```

Or if you need to test for it on `touchmove`, use `elementFromPoint` and the finger coordinates:

```
$(document).on('touchmove', function(e){
    $( document.elementFromPoint(e.touches[0].pageX, e.touches[0].pageY) ) // this is your element
});
```

**Update**

You can use `$.event.props.push("touches");` to normalize the `touches`.